Model comparison for nested regression models that are not symbolically nested
Say I have two nested models and I want to compare them, but they are parameterized differently so that no simple constraint (i.e., setting coefficients to 0) on the larger model corresponds exactly to the smaller model (e.g., because they use different basis functions). We might say they are nested but not symbolically nested.
For example, suppose model 1 is a regression of the outcome on a 4-df natural cubic spline of a predictor, and model 2 is a regression of the outcome on just the predictor as a linear term. These two models are nested, and yet there is no immediately obvious constraint on the spline model that would yield the same parameterization as the linear model. Usually, this isn't a problem, because we can compare nested models using an ANOVA or likelihood ratio (LR) test. But in my case, the model doesn't use the usual OLS or MLE variance matrix, so these tests would not be expected to be accurate. Normally, I would use a Wald test to test the constraints of the larger model that yield a model equivalent to the smaller, but that only works when the two models have coefficients that meaningfully correspond.
Essentially, I'm hoping to find a way to take in the output of the larger model and the output of the smaller model and compute the Wald test statistic assuming the models are nested without needing to specify the constraints that are usually required for a Wald test, but correctly incorporate custom coefficient variances that otherwise cannot be used with the ANOVA or LR test.
Below is an example in R to help fix ideas:
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")

fit1 <- lm(re78 ~ splines::ns(age, df = 4), data = lalonde)
fit2 <- lm(re78 ~ age, data = lalonde)

#Works for basic comparison
anova(fit2, fit1)
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: re78 ~ age
#> Model 2: re78 ~ splines::ns(age, df = 4)
#>   Res.Df        RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)   
#> 1    612 3.3826e+10                               
#> 2    609 3.3007e+10  3 818987331 5.0369 0.00187 **
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

#Doesn't work for sandwich SEs
lmtest::waldtest(fit2, fit1, vcov = sandwich::sandwich)
#> Error in modelCompare(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]], vfun = vcov0): nesting of models cannot be determined

Created on 2024-08-09 with reprex v2.1.1
If one knew how to parameterize the larger model so that the two were symbolically nested, one could perform a Wald test without difficulty, but this isn't always straightforward, and I'm wondering if there is a general solution. The internals of survey:::anova.svyglm() provide some clue for comparing such models, but it seems like the method they use is specific to the type of model that was fit (i.e., wouldn't generalize to arbitrary models like a Wald test on symbolically nested models or LR test would otherwise).

Likely I am missing the point here, why not use AIC as a more general tool for model comparison? In my simplistic view, the Wald/score test evaluates whether a specific set of parameters in a model is significantly different from zero. We are not in that situation here, but we still want to encourage model parsimony against rewarding goodness of fit. So... AICc? :D

(Also, while solutionising this: fit3 <- lm(re78 ~  age + poly(age, raw=TRUE, degree=4), data = lalonde) works fine to prove a point in this case, we just amp the degrees accordingly - and rename the columns...)

@usεr11852 Not all models have a valid AICc or even a likelihood, or inference is only valid using robust SEs. In particular, my application is propensity score weighted models fit using M-estimation with variance that accounts for estimation of the weights. AIC and other likelihood methods don't work here.

Adding a redundant predictor to ensure the models are symbolically nested is a good idea but creates aliased coefficients, which don't always play nice. I'd rather a valid and general statistical solution if there is one rather than an R hack. For applied purposes I think I would just add age as a linear predictor even though it is redundant with the first term of the polynomial. But I noticed it is redundant with the last term of the spline, so again a general solution would be preferred to avoid order dependence.

Fair points - no likelihood, no party... (I have already upvoted this, I am curious to what is the right answer) (Yes, I noticed the aliasing issue... I was like... I need to ridge this now? what is this, 2011?)

See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435893/what-is-a-symbolically-nested-model/436089#436089,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509957/nested-glm-models/510243#510243

For a linear model, say that the full model is $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol\beta + \mathbf{e}_f$ and the reduced model is $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{R} \boldsymbol\alpha + \mathbf{e}_r$. $\mathbf{X}$ is $N \times f$ and $\mathbf{R}$ is $N \times r$ where $r < f$. If the models are nested, then there must be a $(f - r) \times f$ matrix $\mathbf{C}$ such that $\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol\beta  = \mathbf{R} \boldsymbol\alpha$ whenever $\mathbf{C}\boldsymbol\beta = \mathbf{0}$. The question is how to find $\mathbf{C}$.
Regressing $\mathbf{X}$ on $\mathbf{R}$ will give an $N \times f$ matrix of residuals that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{R}$. Let $\boldsymbol\gamma = 
\left(\mathbf{R}'\mathbf{R}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{R}' \mathbf{X}$ so that
$$
\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{R}  \boldsymbol\gamma + \mathbf{\tilde{X}},
$$
where $\mathbf{\tilde{X}} = \mathbf{X} - \mathbf{R}\boldsymbol\gamma$. $\mathbf{\tilde{X}}$ is $N \times f$ but has column rank of $f - r$. Take the singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{\tilde{X}}$ so $\mathbf{\tilde{X}} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{D} \mathbf{V}'$ where $\mathbf{U}$ is $N \times (f - r)$ and orthogonal, $\mathbf{D}$ is $(f - r) \times (f - r)$ and diagonal, and $\mathbf{V}$ is $f \times (f - r)$ and orthogonal. Then
$$
\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol\beta = \mathbf{R}  \boldsymbol\gamma \boldsymbol\beta + \mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{V}'\boldsymbol\beta.
$$
If $\mathbf{V}' \boldsymbol\beta = 0$ then $\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol\beta = \mathbf{R}  \boldsymbol\gamma \boldsymbol\beta$. So we can use $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{V}'$, and $\boldsymbol\alpha = \boldsymbol\gamma \boldsymbol\beta$.
In R:
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")
fit1 <- lm(re78 ~ splines::ns(age, df = 4), data = lalonde)
fit2 <- lm(re78 ~ age, data = lalonde)

X <- model.matrix(fit1)
U <- model.matrix(fit2)
UX_fit <- lm.fit(U, X)
gamma <- coefficients(UX_fit)
X_tilde <- residuals(UX_fit)
X_svd <- svd(X_tilde)
keep <- X_svd$d > 1e-7
Cmat <- t(X_svd$v[,keep,drop=FALSE])

car::linearHypothesis(
  model = fit1, 
  hypothesis.matrix = Cmat,
  vcov. = sandwich::sandwich
)


This did it! Thank you so much for the clear and helpful response. Surprised this method isn't implemented in lmtest, and I couldn't really find any references describing it, but it makes total sense.  I think this is also what is implemented in anova.svyglm().

I assuming I'm missing something straightforward here, but how does $R \gamma$ become $U \gamma$ in the second display equation?

Whoop, that's a typo after fiddling with my notation. Corrected now. Thanks for pointing out.

@Noah: yes, this is method="Wald" in anova.svyglm. For method="LRT", the default, we compute the distribution of the LR statistic even though it's not a likelihood -- but that still needs the contrast matrix.
